# How to delete empty folders with Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an Applescript which prompts the user to select a folder that it will then run the script on. The script runs and basically sorts files into folders. At the end of the script, I want the empty folders to be deleted.

The script works wonderfully until I want to delete the empty folders at the end.

This is what picks the folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set packageFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please choose your 
    logo package folder") as string
end tell
```

And this is the code to delete the empty folders:

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with oneFolder in (get folders of packageFolder)
        if (count items) of oneFolder is 0 then delete oneFolder
    end repeat
end tell
```

I get the following error:

Result:

> error “Can’t get every folder of |”Macintosh HD:Users:michael:
>   Desktop:Logo Package Script Test:\”.” number
>   -1728 from every class cfol» of “Macintosh HD:Users:michael: Desktop: Logo Package Script Test:”

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

#### What about hidden files and folders?

The answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773931/how-to-delete-empty-folders-with-applescript#answer-51775030) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773931/how-to-delete-empty-folders-with-applescript#answer-51774234) in this thread, consider any folder which contains only *hidden<sup>1</sup>* files and/or *hidden* folders to be empty too - resulting in them being deleted, ***which may lead to the loss of important data***.

---

#### A Safer Solution:

Using the following solution an empty folder is considered to be *empty*, only if it *does not* contain a file(s) and/or *non-empty* folder(s) - whether they're visible or hidden. However, the exception to this rule is for any folder containing only a hidden [`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) file - they will be considered empty, and therefore deleted too.

This solution utilizes the Bash [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command and executes it via AppleScripts [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command.

```c
tell application "Finder"
  set packageFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please choose your logo package folder"
  set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of packageFolder
  do shell script "find " & posixPath & " -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete && find " & posixPath & " -empty -type d -delete"
end tell
```

#### Explanation:

Essentially, this AppleScript executes the following Bash commands:

```bash
find /path/to/directory/ -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete
find /path/to/directory/ -empty -type d -delete
```

Let's breakdown the parts of those two commands for a better understanding of what's happening:

**The first command:**

- **`find`** - Search a folder hierarchy for file and folder name(s) which meet a given criteria.
- **`path/to/directory/`** - This (contrived) path points to the directory where the search should begin from. This will be replaced with a real path, i.e. the path to whichever folder is chosen and assigned to the `packageFolder` variable via the [`choose folder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command.

  We provide that path (as a [`POSIX path`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_532)) to the `do shell script` command via the part which reads:

  ```
  set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of packageFolder
  ```

  The [`quoted form`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_613) part ensures the folder path, (i.e. the one assigned to the `posixPath` variable), is provided to `do shell script` avoiding further interpretation by the shell - it essentially ensures the path to the chosen folder, whose name may include spaces, is handled correctly.
- **`-name`** - The name of the file to search for, i.e. `.DS_Store`.
- **`-type f`** - This option specifies that we *only* want to include a regular **f**ile.
- **`-delete`** - This option deletes all files which match the previously specified criteria, i.e. files named `.DS_Store`.

**The second command:**

- **`find`** - *as per the first command.*
- **`path/to/directory/`** - *as per the first command.*
- **`-empty`** - This option specifies that we want to include either a regular file or a directory *only* if it is empty.
- **`-type d`** - This option specifies that we *only* want to include **d**irectories.
- **`-delete`** - *as per the first command.*, however this time we delete empty folders *only*.

---

#### Example Directory (Before and After).

Given a chosen source directory tree like this:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── .hidden-dir-a
│   │   └── foo.txt
│   └── .hidden-dir-b
├── b
│   └── bb
│       ├── .DS_Store
│       └── bbb
├── c
│   └── .hidden.txt
└── d
    ├── dd
    │   └── ddd
    └── quux.txt
```

The resultant directory tree (i.e. after running the AppleScript) will be:

```
.
├── a
│   └── .hidden-dir-a
│       └── foo.txt
├── c
│   └── .hidden.txt
└── d
    └── quux.txt
```

---

#### Refactor:

The current AppleScript (above) assumes that you're using the path which is assigned to the `packageFolder` variable elsewhere in your script, hence it hasn't been changed. Consequently, it introduces the line which reads;

```c
set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of packageFolder
```

to obtain a POSIX path equivalent to the chosen folder path.

However, If the `packageFolder` variable is not used elsewhere, you could refactor the script to the following instead:

```js
tell application "Finder"
  set packageFolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Please choose your logo package folder"))
  do shell script "find " & packageFolder & " -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete && find " & packageFolder & " -empty -type d -delete"
end tell
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Hidden files and folders on MacOS are those whose name begins with a dot (`.`). For instance [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)</sub>

---

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on the latest version of macOS High Sierra

```
set packageFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please choose your 
    logo package folder") as string

tell application "Finder"
    set theFolders to folders of entire contents of folder packageFolder
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theFolders
        set thisFolder to item i of theFolders
        if (count of items of thisFolder) is equal to 0 then
            delete thisFolder
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you wch1zpink. I tried your script and I did not get the error I have been getting, but it didn't delete any empty folders. There are about 4 levels of subdirectories. I don't know if that matters…

I may be able to use parts of this to get it working though. Going to do a quick test.

Comment: @MichaelBruny-Groth If there are four levels of subdirectories, then the folders aren’t empty.  A folder that contains no files but contains an empty folder is not empty.

Comment: CJK — Perhaps I worded my question poorly. I need to delete any empty folders that may occur at any level of the hierarchy. The script provided by wch1zpink does indeed delete empty folders in the targeted folder. So thanks wch1zpink, you did create something that worked.

I found a solution for what I was really trying to solve here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/20188767#message20188767

Comment: **Caution** - This solution considers any folder which contains only hidden file(s) and/or hidden folder(s) to be empty too - resulting in them being deleted, which may lead to the loss of important data. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773931/how-to-delete-empty-folders-with-applescript#answer-51843907) for a safer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working:

```
on killEmpty(fol)

    tell application "Finder"

        repeat with f in (get fol's folders)

            my killEmpty(f)

        end repeat

        if (count items of fol) is 0 then delete fol

    end tell

    end killEmpty



    tell application "Finder"

    repeat with f in (get folders of folder packageFolder)

        my killEmpty(f)

    end repeat

end tell
```

I found this solution here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/20188767#message20188767

Thanks again everyone. Sorry about the inaccurately worded question.

Comment: **Caution** - This solution considers any folder which contains only hidden file(s) and/or hidden folder(s) to be empty too - resulting in them being deleted, which may lead to the loss of important data. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773931/how-to-delete-empty-folders-with-applescript#answer-51843907) for a safer alternative.